# External hard disk inacessible,slow only on my machine [Windows 7 | Ubuntu]

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, external-hard-drive, data-transfer

I have a WD My Passport 1TB external hard disk that gives an extremely slow(`kBs`) transfer speed on both `Windows 7` and `Ubuntu`. Sometimes the hard disk is not even accessible – accessing the contents of the disk freezes the OS, or worse, it asks for formatting the drive.

However, when connecting the same HDD on other computers, it works fine.

I have tried connecting the HDD on all of the 4 USB ports at the back but in vain. One of my friends' suggestion was to replace the power supply. What could be the root cause of my problem?

Comment: Did you use the same USB cable on the other computers?  Is your computer where it is slow using USB 1 ?

Comment: Yes, bro, it's the same USB cable. The external HDD is brand new and its behaviour is the same from the very first day.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (important: run `cmd` command as administrator - click right and choose "run as administrator"

Instructions

1. Click the Start button, and then type `cmd` in the empty text box at the bottom of the menu. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open a command prompt window.
2. Type `netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Windows Vista responds with the message "OK".
3. Close the command prompt to return to the desktop, and begin a new file-copy operation. You should now find that Windows Vista copies the file at the correct speed.

Read more: http://www.ehow.com/how_7358754_speed-up-file_copy-speed-vista.html#ixzz2g5Vjy674